Why this happens when I try to sub-surface to a cylinder?
It looks like some parts gets wrinkled.



Hello what does it give if you inset the top face?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Subsurface division uses an algorithm that depends on topology that has only 4 sided faces. When you have a big polygon like the cap, it doesn't work well.
As suggested, you can inset (i) the caps and you can also "grid fill" (ctrl+f -> grid fill) the circle/polygon inside the inset.
An inset alone will work if the remaining circle and the inset iself are coplanar.

Could you elaborate on what the shortcut "i" does? I pressed it but I couldn't understand if I had to be in edit mode and just select the affected faces/vertices. Thank you so much

Select the top face in Edit mode and press i to inset the face (it will create an inner face, the shading will happen between the former face ring and the new one but not between the new one and the inset face

perfect it worked, thank you. I don't know why but I didn't realize it was something I usually did without realizing it was called like that.

@Andrea In the answer is mentioned the shortcut I and the tool name Inset. How do you usually do that without knowing the shortcut or the name?
